# lxpanel borked since dist-upgrade in Debian Sid

Tags: debian, lxde

On 13-Aug, several LXDE-related packages were installed in my Siduction Linux system. All of these updates came from the Debian repos. Now, lxpanel is not started when I log in, so I have no panel icons nor menus.

On 15-Aug, several more LXDE components were upgraded, and I hoped that these would fix my problem. But, they didn't.

If I manually start lxpanel, it starts without errors, but the panel displayed is completely blank.

Has anyone seen similar problems?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was apparently bugs in the lxde packages. The following upgrade resolved the errors. The packages upgraded became available this afternoon, after I asked the original question:

> Commandline: apt-get dist-upgrade Install: lxsession-data:amd64
>   (0.4.9.2-1+siduction1, automatic), lxsession-edit:amd64
>   (0.4.9.2-1+siduction1), lxsession-logout:amd64 (0.4.9.2-1+siduction1,
>   automatic) Upgrade: libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.36.4-1, 2.37.5-0r0),
>   lxlauncher:amd64 (0.2.2-3+b0~pre2, 0.2.2-3+b0~pre3), lxsession:amd64
>   (0.4.9.2-1, 0.4.9.2-1+siduction1), lxpanel:amd64 (0.5.12-2,
>   0.5.12-2+siduction1)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by uninstalling lxpanel 0.5.12-2 and installing the previous one: lxpanel 0.5.10-1.deb and libmenu-cache1.deb (downloaded here http://packages.debian.org/stable/lxpanel). I hope you are able to do that...

Comment: Thank you as well, Enzo. As Raphael Ahrens surmises, I am unable to do that. I am apparently too far down the upgrade path to a new version of LXDE. Several packages depend on the newer versions, while older packages depend on packages that have been removed, entirely. What a mess!

Answer (score 0):

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall lxpanel
```

then restart your PC.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in my Debian Jessie. I removed the `lxpanel`, `lxsession`, `lxterminal`, `lxsession-default-apps` and `openbox` folders under `.config` directory. After that `lxpanel` started again normally and everything was back to default settings.
So it seems that some configuration fileformat was changed in an update. My quess would be `lxsession` but I can't verify any more.